# Android TextView setText without ID

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

I have created an xml page that holds 2 textviews and a seekbar all without ids.
The class CustomSeekBar creates these objects using the xml page as a basic structure.
You can see space for the textviews on my emulator, but I am having a hard time figuring out to set the text. Obviously I am missing something, because there is no way for the CustomSeekBar class to be able to tell which textview I want to set the text for.

How do I set the text of each individual view without giving each textview a hardcoded ID?
The reason I say without a hardcoded ID, is because if each textview is named, then when one textview's text needs to be changed, won't all the textview's texts, with that ID, change?
How would I call the specific textview ID since my customseekbar class is in a composite relationship with the activity?

Activity that calls everything.

```
public class ColorsActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
SeekBarAdaptor seekBarAdaptor;

//List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
 ArrayList<CustomSeekBar> seekBarArrayList=null;
// TextView myValueText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seekbarlist);

    //Initialize ListView        
    ListView lstTest= getListView();

     //Initialize our ArrayList
    seekBarArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomSeekBar>();

    //Initialize our array adapter 
    seekBarAdaptor = new SeekBarAdaptor(ColorsActivity.this, R.layout.seekbars, seekBarArrayList);

    CustomSeekBar red = new CustomSeekBar(this, "red", 1);
    //CustomSeekBar blue = new CustomSeekBar(this, "blue");
    //CustomSeekBar green = new CustomSeekBar(this, "green");

    //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
    lstTest.setAdapter(seekBarAdaptor);

    seekBarArrayList.add(red);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(blue);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(green);

    Amarino.connect(this, "00:11:11:21:05:53");
}







}
```

CustomSeekBar class

```
public class CustomSeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

Context myContext;
TextView myValue;
TextView myLabel;
SeekBar mySeekBar;

CustomSeekBar(Context context, String label, int ID){
    myContext = context;


    myValue = new TextView(myContext);
    mySeekBar = new SeekBar(myContext);

    myValue.setText(label);
    mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
    myValue.setText(progress);

    Amarino.sendDataToArduino(myContext, "00:11:11:21:05:53", 'A', progress);
 }
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

 }
 public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
 }


}
```

seekbarlist.xml holds my list view for the custom list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

seekbars.xml is the structure of each custom list item (CustomSeekBar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/seekBarLayout">
     <TextView
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="#aa0000"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
      /> 

      <TextView
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:background="#aa0000"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />


     <SeekBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:max="255"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you don't have a name and I don't know you, how would I call you among the crowd to give you the answer?

Comment: I have given the question a brief explanation with a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

why would you have to name them the same ID name why not 
    @+id/textview1 and @+id/textview2 and then reference the two text boxes in your code I don't understand what is stopping you?

Comment: I would not name them the same ID. There are 2 textviews (in seekbars.xml) per CustomSeekBar object. These IDs could be different. But what happens when I have more than one CustomSeekBar object? There will be 4, 6, 8, etc textviews. Half of them will have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDs as @bmporter12 said.  You can have duplicate IDs, provided that Android has a place to start looking from when you tell it to `findViewById`.  So, in your adapter, in `getView()`, you would inflate your new `row` from seekbars.xml and then do `row.findViewById(R.id.textView1)` and `row.findViewById(R.id.textView2)`.

If you need to set it from outside the adapter, then depending on where you're getting the signal to set a TextView, either your CustomSeekBar could ask the Activity for its entry at a particular position in the adapter or it could use the View parameter passed in an onClick callback.